# Multiplying two variables in CVXPY

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

I'm in need of an LP where you can multiply two non-constants. Here is the following code that I am trying to perform:

```
import cvxpy as cvx
a = cvx.Variable()
b = cvx.Variable()
c = cvx.Variable()
obj = cvx.Maximize(((0.4270437386 * a) + (0.1737677971 * b) + (0.21763175116 * c) - 0.03)  /  (((((2 * a * 0.424718270)  * b) * (0.195770376 ** 0.5)) * (0.022090814 ** 0.5)) * ((2 * c * -0.041137487) * b * (0.194241184 ** 0.5) * (0.022090814 ** 0.5)) * (2 * a * 0.363033596 * c * (0.195770376** 0.5) * (0.194241184 ** 0.5))))
```

Unfortunately this raises an error:

```
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Cannot multiply two non-constants.
```

This stems from several areas in the denominator of `obj`, such as `(2 * a * 0.424718270)  * b)`.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any LP programs where we can do this sort of thing? Is it even possible.

Comment: Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774270/how-to-convert-quadratic-to-linear-program for details on how to linearize the product of decision variables in the objective, converting a bilinear optimization problem (which you describe) to a linear optimization problem.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are asking a **linear programming** package to optimize for a **non-linear** objective function.  This is much more than a technical issue.  The methods used to solve linear programming problems do not make sense and cannot be tweaked.