# Linearize equation for PuLP

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I'm trying to add a non-linear constraint to my model that describes as the amount of heated water (`m_heated` @ `temp_heated`) required to add to other cold/inlet/netowrk water mass (`m_inlet` @ `temp_inlet`) to result in a defined temperature `temp_set`. The total flow rate `m_total` is total mixture, given by adding both flow rates `m_total = m_heated + m_inlet`. Assuming the same fluid, so I'm disregarding the specific heat capacity.

```
temp_set = ( m_heated * temp_heated + (m_total - m_heated) * temp_inlet ) / m_total
```

Since my goal is to find the m_heated (to add to the optimization problem), this simplifies to:

```
m_heated = m_total * (temp_set - temp_inlet) / (temp_heated - temp_inlet)
```

However, this results in a non-linear equation (`m_total`, `temp_set`, `temp_inlet` are known), and both `m_heated` and `temp_heated` are not, and they add to other constrains as well.

I used:

```
milp += m_heated[t] = m_total * (temp_set - temp_inlet) / (temp_heated[t] - temp_inlet)
```

But it retuns that "Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied". Is there any way of adding this to PuLP as linear?

Comment: You could use linear interpolation. I would probably throw this first at an NLP solver and see how that works. Gurobi cal also do non-convex quadratic constraints, so that may be another candidate.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a straightforward way of adding this to PuLP as linear because, mathematically, it's not linear.

See for example the discussion here for some ideas on how to solve this:
[How to convert quadratic to linear program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774270/how-to-convert-quadratic-to-linear-program)

Consult also the Math Stackexchange or the Operations Research Stackexchange for additional discussion.